# Hide home folders for users

Tags: home-directory, users

I have a ubuntu desktop edition set up as server at my home and this installation has a lot of users.
I hav a administrator account and all other accounts are standard accounts.

At the moment everyone can see the other peoples home directories and the files in it.
I would like to change this that the users can only access their own home directories. But I would like to still be able to see the other users home directories.

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the permissions in the users home folders. For instance, if the user folders are:

```
/home/alice
/home/john
/home/jack
```

You should do :

```
chmod -R go-rwx /home/alice
chmod -R go-rwx /home/john
chmod -R go-rwx /home/jack
```

Comment: That works, but I would like to be able to access the directories as administrator.

Comment: The root user can still access them.